# How to dispaly incoorect Login toast validation

Tags: android, sqlite, authentication, toast

In the login form check the username and password in database values,if its correct show the toast as "welcome" and if its wrong  show the toast as "incorrect".But in my coding if the password is wrong the both toast will display.

And If my database null means what type of condition makes a toast

I'm new to android,I know it's a simple question, I tried a lot.Help me please

```
signin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Database db=new Database(Sin.this);



        SQLiteDatabase sb=db.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor c=sb.rawQuery("select * from newuser",null);


        c.moveToFirst();

        for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)

            {

                if((c.getString(1).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(un.getText().toString()))&&(c.getString(3).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(pass.getText().toString())))

                {

                    Toast.makeText(Sin.this, "Welcome "+c.getString(0),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

                     finish();
                    Intent in=new Intent(Sin.this,MainActivity.class);

                    startActivity(in);


        }


                else 
        {
            Toast.makeText(Sin.this, "Invalid Credentials",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }


                 c.moveToNext();
    }


}
});
```

Comment: try to use  equals in your Condition

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is in query

```
String username = un.getText().toString();
    String pwd = pass.getText().toString();
    String query="select * from newuser where userName = "+"'"+ username+"'"+" and "+"password="+"'"+pwd+"'";
 Cursor c=sb.rawQuery(query,null);
  if(c.getCount()>0)
 {
   Toast.makeText(Sin.this, "Welcome "+c.getString(0),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

                 finish();
                Intent in=new Intent(Sin.this,MainActivity.class);

                startActivity(in);
 }
 else 
    Toast.makeText(Sin.this, "Invalid Credentials",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: if any of the field is wrong c.getCount() will return 0 so it will go in else

Comment: thanks for the response                                              It didn't check the database